# Black screen in Youtube Iframe (Android Application)

Tags: android, cordova, webview, youtube

I'm creating a Phonegap Android application, I've placed a Youtube Iframe inside a webview. But when playing a video only the sound works and the screen stays black.

I've found a solution, but I can't seem to get it working. I've got to add the code "getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);" inside App.java. Does anyone know how to implement this code?

**App.java**

```
package com.package.name;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

public class App extends DroidGap {
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private AdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            doAdMob();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

private void doAdMob() {
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "CODE");
    LinearLayout layout = super.root;
    layout.addView(adView);
    layout.setHorizontalGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    adView.loadAd(request);
}
}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onCreate method is where you need to add the line:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    this.appView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            doAdMob();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```